# Abstract Class Lambda Function in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting confused in the usage of abstract class lambda function usage in PHP returning bool value. I want to define a lambda function which takes in an obj type input and returns bool and this return value is stored in a variable. And I want to leave the implementation to the child classes. How to define this function? I am currently writing below which is giving me error:

```
$var = (function(OBJ type): bool);

?'input' => this::var
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for better understanding.

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractClass {
    abstract public function getFunction(object $callback): bool;
}

class ChildClass extends AbstractClass {
    public bool $get_function_result;

    public function getFunction(object $callback): bool {
        $this->get_function_result = is_callable($callback);
        return $this->get_function_result;
    }
}

$instance = new ChildClass();
$result = $instance->getFunction(function () {});
var_dump($result);
```

You can read more about abstract classes here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Update:

```
<?php
class JustClass {
    public object $example;
    function __construct() {
        $this->example = function(object $callback): bool {
            return true;
        };
    }
}
$instance = new JustClass;
echo ($instance->example)(function() {});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The above mentioned is a normal function. Could you please help me in writing this in the form of lambda function?
Something like: $get_function_result = function(object obj): bool; Why is this wrong and what should be corrected in this?

Comment: @ADT, you cannot declare properties in abstract class. Only methods, which must be defined in child class, you can just define in child class public properties, which might be inherited by child class.

I've added example of property-lambda-function of class in my answer.